Uploading file to ASP.NET Core Web API using VBA
I'm struggling to upload a CSV file from local drive to a Web API.
Sub Upload()
    Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim url As String
    Dim filename, resp As String
    Dim boundary, payload As String

    filename = "C:\temp\File2.csv" '& ";type=text/csv"

    boundary = "-----------------"
    
    url = "https://localhost:7102/api/v1/SThree/upload/bkm_volume"

    objHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "accept", "*/*"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
    
    payload = boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; file=" & Chr(34) & filename & Chr(34) & vbCrLf & boundary
    
    Open filename For Input As #1
    contents = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1
    
    ' Not sure if the contents need to be in the payload or if it's supposed to just be the filename
    payload = payload & vbCrLf & contents & vbCrLf & boundary
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", LenB(payload)
    objHTTP.send payload

    If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then 'success
    Else
        resp = objHTTP.responseText
        MsgBox resp
    End If
End Sub

The API is:
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile? file, string path)
{
     if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
     {
         return BadRequest("No file provided.");
     }
     
     if (file.Length > Definitions.MaxFileSize)
     {
         return BadRequest("Invalid path. The specified file was too large.");
     }

     var outputDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "UploadFiles");
     var tempPath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, file.FileName);

     if (!Directory.Exists(outputDirectory))
     {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
     }

     await using (var stream = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create))
     {
         await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
     }
}


https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+post+file+site:stackoverflow.com or specifically https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

Have you tested your API by posting from a static web page with a basic form?  Is the issue specifically with the VBA?

The API is fine, I've tested it using Swagger without issue. I've also see the wordpress and page and other articles and tried these before posting here. I'm posting to see if someone knows what's wrong with the code, why it doesn't work. I'm not in the habit of asking here because I'm too lazy to search

No intended suggestion of laziness on my part.  I've used that WordPress code as-is and it worked fine for me.   What response do you get when you try it out?

I'm "getting unexpected end of stream"

Where exactly are you getting that?

I see that in the MsgBox message MsgBox resp
